# Installing android project on another phone without usb connection

Tags: android, testing

Is there a way for me to send a friend of mine the project files of my Android project and for them to run it from their phone?

I am new to Android development and currently I run the application on my device via USB, however if I want to pass it to someone else for testing purposes is the only option to have them plug their phone in to my computer via USB?

Comment: You might wish to post this to the Android SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the the APK file (which you can give to them in multiple ways). Make sure you have Ant and the other necessary tools installed and in your path. Then open the command line and move the directory where you're project is and run `ant release`. You should now have another subdirectory called *bin* (short for *binary*). In there is a file called '*yourprojectname*-release-unsigned.apk'. This is the file that you would have to give to your friend.

**However**, be aware that sometimes the android device (especially if the dev settings are not enabled) will not let you install from an unsigned package, so you might also want to sign it. Google has documentation on how to do that in multiple ways [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

As to how you will give them the APK, you can give it to them in multiple ways:

1. You can give it to them on a USB drive (or some similar method) which they can then put on their computer and then directly on to their Android device and install from there using the file manager.
2. You can put it on a server (like Dropbox) from which they can download it directly onto their Android device and install via file manager getting rid of the middle step of using another computer and a USB cable in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can send him apk file. It is something like jar for java project. If you use android studio you can find this file in:

```
yourProjectFolder/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

Comment: And how would he launch it on his phone?

Comment: Hi should copy this file on his phone and he has to find it on phone and install. (he has to just open this file on his phone). Additionally device will ask him if he allows to install application from unknown source.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to send a friend of mine the project files of my
>   Android project and for them to run it from their phone?

When you say project files, if you are referring to Android source code. You can do the following.

1. In your desktop, zip the app source code and share it with your friend. He can import the android project into his workspace and do a Clean - Build.

Therefore, the app will be signed with his debug certificate and install in his phone.

someone else for testing purposes

If only APK file is needed, you can share it in email. He can open the email in his mobile device. Download the attachment and install the application.

Note - To do this, in Devices Settings, Settings -> Security. - Allow Unknown Sources should be checked.